# Installing vim with homebrew assistance

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

I tried to install YouCompleteMe on Mac for vim, but I've been using the system vim which is version 7.3. I tried to update my vim using homebrew by typing `brew install vim` and everything seemed to be fine.

When I type `vim` I still see the system vim loading (version 7.3).

I feel like I'm missing a step that's keeping me from using the updated `vim` I got from homebrew. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

For reference when I type `which vim` I get the following output `/usr/bin/vim`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40):

Just install vim via homebrew:

```
brew install vim
```

Then restart your shell:

```
exec -l $SHELL
```

And check the version:

```
$ vim --version|head -n 1
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar  9 2016 19:07:39)
```

Comment: ```exec -l $SHELL``` did the trick. before that, although ```which vim``` says it's homebrew's vim, when typed ```vim``` it was running system's vim.

Comment: @inanc exactly my findings as well, was stuck until I realized I needed to reload the shell.

Comment: Restarting shell fixed it

Comment: it is interesting that sourcing ~/.zshrc which contains new ```PATH``` that has ```/usr/local/bin/``` first still didn't resolve the issue, but the restart does the trick.

Answer (score 19):

You should probably have done `brew install vim --with-override-system-vi`. This will replace default vim path.

Comment: `--override-system-vi` is now `--with-override-system-vi`

Comment: Options appear to have gone as of Homebrew 2.0.0 (https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/)

Comment: Normally you don't need this option anymore. Just restart a shell session and the `vim` command should be the one compiled and installed by Homebrew.

Answer (score 9):

You're loading your system vim first, as you can see by `which vim` returning `/usr/bin/vim` instead of `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

`/usr/local/bin` is homebrew's path.

Make sure that your path lists `/usr/local/bin` *before* `/usr/bin`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

This will allow homebrew's `vim` to be sourced *before* the system `vim`.

---

To view your path:

```
echo "$PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than reinstalling vim you can move your current vim to vim73 (or something similar).

First check if `/usr/local/bin` is present in `PATH` environment variable. Doing `echo $PATH` on your terminal should do that.

Install vim with homebrew if you haven't already.

```
brew install vim
```

Then move your current vim installation.

```
mv /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim73
```

Run `which vim` to confirm. It should say `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

Answer (score 1):

`brew install vim --with-override-system-vi` (missing the `with-`)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Run this command and it will be fixed.