# Copy/Paste from/to clipboard in vim stopped working

Tags: vim

The problem is that copy/paste from/to vim to the clipboard stopped working. I'm not sure why...

In `:reg` I don't see the `+` and `*` buffers too...

Here's my [.vimrc](https://github.com/brslv/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc), if needed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

OK, I figured it out. The problem was I was using the system vim (the one, preinstalled on my Mac). I've find it out with: `which vim`. It returned `/usr/bin/vim`. The problem with the default vim is that it's not compiled with the `clipboard` option (run `vim --version | grep clipboard` and if you see `-clipboard`, it means you don't have the "copy/paste to/from clipboard functionality).

Now, if you don't have vim installed with the homebrew, install it. Than, in your .zshrc (or .bashrc) file, provide the path to the `/usr/local/bin` file, so that it overrides the `/usr/bin` (before it). Now you're using the homebrew's vim, which comes with the `+clipboard` option enabled.

Have fun copy-pasting. :)

Comment: Right on, you just have to make sure you do this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24621347/1254111

otherwise you will still be loading the ``default`` vim.
This is what I did in my ``.zshrc``:
``export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH``

Comment: I dunno why this question is marked as duplicated, while the "original" question has thousands of answers that do not point out this simple solution.