# tmux Using the Wrong Version of Vim

Tags: vim, homebrew, zsh, tmux

I installed Vim and tmux using `brew install vim` and `brew install tmux`, and when running `vim --version` outside tmux with zsh as the default shell I get this:

```
macOS version - arm64
Included patches: 1-3550
Compiled by Homebrew
```

which is what I want. However, when running `vim --version` in a tmux session, I get this:

```
macOS version
Included patches: 1-2029
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

which is not what I want.

I was thinking that this could have something to do with the arm64 architecture of my processor. I installed Homebrew with this terminal command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Relating https://stackoverflow.com/a/24621347/4957508

Comment: Are you running a different shell inside `tmux`? Your `PATH` may be set differently in that shell. Regardless, this is not a programming question. Try unix.stackexchange.com or apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I noticed that when typing `type -a vim` outside a tmux session I got:

```
vim is /opt/homebrew/bin/vim
vim is /usr/bin/vim
```

But, when typing `type -a vim` **inside** a tmux session I got:

```
vim is /usr/bin/vim
vim is /opt/homebrew/bin/vim
```

which means that, for some unknown reason, the paths to the different versions of vim got swapped in a tmux session.

I solved this by putting the following in my .zshrc:

```
alias vi=/opt/homebrew/bin/vim
alias vim=/opt/homebrew/bin/vim
```

This works because it forces the `vi` and `vim` commands to use the version of vim found in the path I specified in the .zshrc.

I hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.